# How to change the href of <a> tag in CodeIgniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I need to change the href of `<a>` tag in CodeIgniter pagination.
CodeIgniter's `$this->pagination->create_links();` function creates links like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/admin/view/3">3</a>
```

But, I need the page number(3) at the end of all segments.
Like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/admin/view/field/created/3">3</a>
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/admin/view/field/created/order/asc/3">3</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the URL as config variable:

```
$config = array('base_url' => site_url('/admin/view/field/created'));
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$this->pagination->create_links();
```

For more config possibilities, see [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html).

Comment: How does that answer his question of a floating pagination segment?

Comment: @giraff: the site url is not fixed, and the segments can be changed, and i want the page number at the last every time......

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. Easiest solution? Reconfigure your URL structure so the pagination is always the first segment. To not mess up the sorting fields just make sure the page always loads with a pagination, ie when it first loads put a 0 in that segment. Other than changing your set up to use query strings I don't think you can move where the pagination segment is easily, I suppose you could do some if logic in your config such as:

```
if(is_numeric($this->uri->segment(2)
{
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
} else if (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3) {
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
}
```

But honestly that could get pretty ugly depending on how many extra segments you're adding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate the uri segment of the "page number" and the "base url" like this:

```
// Parsing the URI into an associative array
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);

$segments = count($uri);

// Calculate the uri segment and base url
if ($segments > 1) {
   $uri_segment  = 3 + $segments - 1; // 3 segments "index.php/admin/view/ + SORT_SEGMENTS - PAGE_SEGMENT

   array_pop($uri); // Pop the page number
   $base_url     = site_url('admin/view/'. implode('/', $uri));
} else {
   $uri_segment  = 4;
   $base_url     = site_url('admin/view/');
}

// Pagination config
$config['base_url']         = $base_url;
$config['uri_segment']      = $uri_segment;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['total_rows']       = YOUR_CONFIG;
$config['num_links']        = YOUR_CONFIG;
$config['per_page']         = YOUR_CONFIG; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

$pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

PD: I'm argentinian and my English skills are a little poor